# Building VS Solution with .NET Standard components

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, azure-devops, .net-standard

I'm having issues building a Visual Studio 2017 solution, where one of the class library projects contains references to .NET Standard / Core component (`Microsoft.Exensions.Logging`).

My class library is **.NET 4.6.2**, and referencing **.NET Standard 2.01**.

Everything builds and runs fine within Visual Studio, however, when trying to create a build in Visual Studio Online, i get the following error. The build had previously been working, and i am doing a Nuget package restore.

```
>     MyWeb.csproj (1080, 5)
>     MyWeb.csproj(1080,5): Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package
> Restore to download them. For more information, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is
> ..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.
```

Any insight?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you include the Nuget Restore build task before the solution build?

Comment: Yes, i have the Nuget package restore before the solution build. This error only started happening after introducing a .NET core / standard dependency into the solution

Comment: Have you checked to see if the [.NET Standard version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) is compatible with the framework you are targeting? It seems that both the .NET Standard version number and target framework are relevant to the question, so you should add them.

Comment: updated with .net framework and .net standard versions

Comment: Ensure that your build agent and the build step target VS 2017.  I'm not sure if that helps this case at all, but it helped with a different issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the new projects? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? Try to add NuGet Tool Installer task (install 4.3.0) before NuGet restore task.

Comment: Have the console app target 4.6.1 instead of 4.6.2

Comment: Why would changing the framework to 4.6.1 fix it?